Error 401: "Missing authorization details for accessing model serving endpoints" with OAuth Token on Databricks
I am trying to generate an OAuth token for my Azure Databricks workspace to access a model serving API in production. The code I’m using generates a token successfully, but I keep receiving a 401 error with the message "Missing authorization details for accessing model serving endpoints" when I try to use it.
Here's the code I'm using:
import requests

# Azure Databricks and Managed Service Principal Details
client_id = "XXXX"  # Application ID
client_secret = "XXXXX"  # Client Secret
workspace_url = "XXXXXX"  # Databricks workspace URL

# Databricks-specific endpoint URL for token generation
token_endpoint_url = f"{workspace_url}/oidc/v1/token"

# Function to get OAuth access token with all-apis scope
def get_workspace_oauth_token():
    response = requests.post(
        token_endpoint_url,
        auth=(client_id, client_secret),
        data={
            "grant_type": "client_credentials",
            "scope": "all-apis"
        }
    )
    response.raise_for_status()  # Check for request errors
    return response.json(), response.json().get("access_token")

# Generate the access token
response, access_token = get_workspace_oauth_token()
print("OAuth token generated successfully:", access_token)

The OAuth token seems to be generated without any issues. I’ve also ensured that my Service Principal has the necessary permissions to access the model serving endpoint in the Databricks workspace.
However, when using this token to call the model serving API endpoint, I get the following response:
{
    "error_code": 401,
    "message": "Missing authorization details for accessing model serving endpoints"
}

Additional Context:
I have already assigned permissions to the Service Principal in Databricks.
I’m using the all-apis scope to cover the model serving endpoint.
Has anyone encountered this issue or have suggestions on what could be causing the 401 error?

have you registered the client id in databricks?

Try the code given in below solution. @Gustavo Carvalho

The error says that the authorization details you have given after retrieving the token is not valid.
Here are the few approaches on how to make a request using the token you have.
In python use below sample code.
import requests,json
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
}
body = {
  "dataframe_split": {
    "columns": ["prompt"],
    "data": [["Hello, I'm a language model,"]]
  }
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body)
response.json()

Give body according to your model, and make sure you given Authorization as Bearer <token> .
Output:

Next, in any Api request tool.

In Header tab add Authorization and value as Bearer <token>, if you don't mention bearer then it will give 401 error meaning your authorization is not correct.

This was a nasty one took me hours to finally figure out, in this documentation Fetch OAuth token you will notice the curl has last line data-urlencode, the line above this doesn't have new line backslash

So when i was running this curl the token was getting generated but it was missing the authorization_details
For fixing this you have to make sure that your fetch token curl is complete and looks like this
      export CLIENT_ID=<client-id>
      export CLIENT_SECRET=<client-secret>
      export ENDPOINT_ID=<endpoint-id>
      export ACTION=<action>

      curl --request POST \
      --url <token-endpoint-URL> \
      --user "$CLIENT_ID:$CLIENT_SECRET" \
      --data 'grant_type=client_credentials&scope=all-apis' \
      --data-urlencode 'authorization_details=[{"type":"workspace_permission","object_type":"serving-endpoints","object_path":"'"/serving-endpoints/$ENDPOINT_ID"'","actions": ["'"$ACTION"'"]}]'

Now this is complete and should get you the response
